# Tuple index out of range c.fetchone()

Tags: tuples, create-table

I am working my way through a simple routine for my GCSE's and have got a little stuck.  Unfortunately my teacher isn't a coder and always refers the class to Google when we get stuck!

I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Controlled assesment Task 2 - Copy.py", line 33, in <module>
productinfo = found[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

When running this routine

```
        c.execute("SELECT GTIN8 From Products WHERE GTIN8=?", (validcode,))

        found = c.fetchone()

        barcode = found[0]
        productinfo = found[1]
        price = found[2]

        c.execute("INSERT INTO ProductData (barcode,productinfo,price) VALUES(?,?,?)")
        db_new.commit()
        print(barcode, productinfo, price)
```

Querying this table

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Products(GTIN8 string, Product_Description text, Cost float)") #Creates a table with fields and data types
Products=[['12345670','TShirt', 10.00],
     ('52647819','Shirt', 20.00),       #This is the product table
     ('15678348','Polo', 15.00),
     ('15975324','Hoodie', 30.00),
     ('42675136','Dress', 20.00),
     ('42697312','Skirt', 12.00),
     ('86316422','Shorts', 18.00),
     ('17653749','Jeans', 35.00),
     ('93462815','Socks', 5.00),
     ('00000000','test', 1.50),
     ('36478545','Shoes', 40.00)]
c.executemany("INSERT INTO Products VALUES (?,?,?)",Products)
```

I have scratched my head sore trying to see why the second column is not being returned!

Please can someone give me a steer.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what language this is written in, but in general, `index out of range` means you're using `[n]` where there is nothing at position `n`. And it mentions `productinfo = found[1]`, so I guess that `found` hasn't got a `[1]`. If you remove that line, does it then give the same error for `price = found[2]`?

Comment: It's written in Python 3.5. Found[0] refers to the first column of the table, which is returned sucessfully [1] & [2] refer to the 2nd and 3rd columns, which are not returned.

Comment: Removing [1] results in the same error for [2].  I'm trying to have a user input of a verified barcode and setup a purchase of x number of units relating to that barcode.  The query should return the contents of the row returned from the correctly inputted barcode. I want to create a new db table containing the returned product and cost information relating to the barcode. The number of units is multipled by the cost and output as a total.

Comment: I think I got it fixed!  I replaced the variable GTIN8 with an asterisks at  c.execute("SELECT GTIN8 From Products WHERE GTIN8=?", (validcode,))